# JRebel not working on external tomcat 7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, server, jrebel

For some reason I can't get `JRebel` work on external `Tomcat 7` with Eclipse. Everything works fine if I use server runtime in IDE, but if I launch server from command line and deploy application externally, JRebel doesn't reflect my changes to server.

Here is how I configured and deployed my project:

- Enabled `JRebel` on project from projects configuration tab
- Startup set to `Run locally from command line`
- Created `catalina-jrebel.bat` according to generated configuration
- Built project using maven
- launched server using `catalina-jrebel.bat run`
- Deployed war file on server from Tomcat's `application manager`

Now, if I modify my sample Servlet and save, nothing happens. Application behavior doesn't change, nothing in console.

Am I missing something, and how to debug the problem?

Here is the content of `catalina-jrebel.bat`

```
@echo off
set REBEL_BASE=C:\Users\tutoivon\.jrebel
set JAVA_OPTS="-javaagent:C:\SLO\eclipse\plugins\org.zeroturnaround.eclipse.embedder_6.4.4.RELEASE\jrebel\jrebel.jar"  %JAVA_OPTS%
call "%~dp0\catalina.bat" %*
```

Answer (score 1):

Some things you can check by yourself:

1. Server starts up with JRebel banner - so you can be sure JRebel Agent was actually attached to server.
2. In the banner it says that you have valid license - no license, no reloading.
3. The built `.war` contains a `rebel.xml` inside `WEB-INF/classes` - this helps JRebel to find the location of classes updated by IDE.
4. The paths in `rebel.xml` are absolute and correct, no placeholders (e.g. `${rebel.workspace.path}`) are used - if placeholders are used, then they must be defined by passing e.g. `-Drebel.workspace.path=/path/to/workspace` to `JAVA_OPTS`. If done correctly, JRebel will also log a line such as `JRebel: Monitoring directory '/path/in/rebelxml'` in server log.

If you still can't get it to work after these steps, contact support@zeroturnaround.com.